# How to deal with Nan value when using rioxarray rio.reproject()?

Tags: interpolation, rasterio, resampling, rioxarray, xarray

I was trying to use `rio.reproject_match()` to match the resolution of two xarray datasets. However, when I used resample methods like `Resampling.bilinear` or `Resampling.average`, a large area would become Nan value after reprojection and a lot of information was lost.

I guess the reason is that `rio.reproject()` will not skip the Nan value. A simple example:

```py
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray as rxr
import numpy as np
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, np.nan, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
x = np.arange(100, 116, 4)
y = np.arange(36, 20, -4)

foo = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[y, x], dims=['y', 'x'])
foo = foo.rio.write_crs('EPSG:4326')

foo_resampled = foo.rio.reproject(
    foo.rio.crs,
    resolution=8,
    resampling=Resampling.average,
)
```

`foo`:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (y: 4, x: 4)>
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5., nan,  7.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10., 11., 12.],
       [13., 14., 15., 16.]])
Coordinates:
  * y            (y) int32 36 32 28 24
  * x            (x) int32 100 104 108 112
    spatial_ref  int32 0
```

The result `foo_resampled` is:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (y: 2, x: 2)>
array([[ nan,  5.5],
       [11.5, 13.5]])
Coordinates:
  * x            (x) float64 102.0 110.0
  * y            (y) float64 34.0 26.0
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    _FillValue:  1.7976931348623157e+308
```

However, what I want is:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (y: 2, x: 2)>
array([[ 2.66666667,  5.5       ],
       [11.5       , 13.5       ]])
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 34.0 26.0
  * x        (x) float64 102.0 110.0
```

The last one will retain more information. From [rasterio document](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.enums.html#rasterio.enums.Resampling), it says:

> Average resampling, computes the weighted average of all **non-NODATA** contributing pixels.

I think it should have skipped the Nan value when doing calculations? How can I get the result I expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't actually set a NoData value.  Explicitly set `nan` as the NoData value.

```
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray as rxr
import numpy as np
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, np.nan, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
x = np.arange(100, 116, 4)
y = np.arange(36, 20, -4)

foo = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[y, x], dims=['y', 'x'])
foo.rio.write_crs('EPSG:4326', inplace=True)

foo_resampled = foo.rio.reproject(
    foo.rio.crs,
    resolution=8,
    resampling=Resampling.average,
)

# Set NaN as NoData
foo.rio.write_nodata(np.nan, inplace=True)
foo_resampled_nodata = foo.rio.reproject(
    foo.rio.crs,
    resolution=8,
    resampling=Resampling.average,
    nodata=np.nan # Set NaN as NoData
)

print(foo_resampled)
print(foo_resampled_nodata)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (y: 2, x: 2)>
array([[ nan,  5.5],
       [11.5, 13.5]])
Coordinates:
  * x            (x) float64 102.0 110.0
  * y            (y) float64 34.0 26.0
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    _FillValue:  1.7976931348623157e+308

<xarray.DataArray (y: 2, x: 2)>
array([[ 2.66666667,  5.5       ],
       [11.5       , 13.5       ]])
Coordinates:
  * x            (x) float64 102.0 110.0
  * y            (y) float64 34.0 26.0
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    _FillValue:  nan
```

Comment: This is actually what I want. I had no idea that I needed to set the NoData value. Hope others could check the [Nodata Management](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/nodata_management.html) document first. Thanks a lot!